# Spring Boot Model Class only accessing Oracle table when using Synonym

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring boot application and need to create a model class that accesses a database table.

Due to permissions configurations in the db, a SELECT only works using the username in front of the table name or using an Oracle Synonym.

In SQL Developer:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE; // This doesn't work - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SELECT * FROM MYUSER.MYTABLE;  // This works
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE_SYNONYM; // This works
```

In Oracle, MYTABLE_SYNONYM is a Public SYNONYM to MYTABLE.

So the two last SELECTS above are acessing the same MYTABLE table.

In the application:

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "MYTABLE") // This doesn't work - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
//@Table(name = "MYUSER.MYTABLE") // This DOESN'T work - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
@Table(name = "MYTABLE_SYNONYM") // This works
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
....
}
```

My question is why @Table(name = "MYUSER.MYTABLE") is generating the "ORA-00942" error if SELECT * FROM MYUSER.MYTABLE works fine in SQL Developer?

In the application, the only way it works is using the Public SYNONYM.

But I wouldn't like to use a Synonym because it can cause confusion and difficulties for the application maintenance as the name is different from the actual table name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation `@Table(name = "MYTABLE")` doesn't work because the user that you are using to access the database has access to another schema as the default schema.

The annotation `@Table(name = "MYUSER.MYTABLE")` doesn't work because this is not the right syntax to access a table in a different schema. You need to use the annotation  `@Table(name="MYTABLE", schema="MYUSER")` that explicitly says to use the schema MYUSER and search for a table named MYTABLE in that schema. This syntax is explained in the javadoc of the annotation [Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#schema--):

> (Optional) **The schema of the table**.
> Defaults to the default schema for user.

The last annotation `@Table(name = "MYTABLE_SYNONYM")` because somebody defined a synonim MYTABLE_SYNONYM to access the table MYTABLE on the schema MYUSER. This is transparent from the point of view of the user accessing the db.

Comment: Great answer. Very well explained. I used @Table(name="MYTABLE", schema="MYUSER") and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!